# Update input tag value on anchor tag click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a div

```
@{int index = 0;}
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.lstFiles.Count; i++)
{
     <div id="attachmentDetail(@index)" name="attachmentDetail(@index)" class="panel-body">
         <a asp-action="Download" asp-controller="Admin" asp-route-realName=Model.lstFiles[i].RealName>@Model.lstFiles[i].FileName</a>
         <a onclick="btnDelFile_Click(@index)" id="btnDelFile{@index}" class="pull-right" title="delete"><img height="20" width="20" src="@Url.Content("~/images/delete.jpg")" /></a>
         <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.lstFiles[i].IsDeleted" hidden />
         <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.lstFiles[i].FileId" hidden />
         <hr />
     </div>
     index++;
 }
```

I want to update `@Model.lstFiles[i].IsDeleted` value on `btnDelFile_Click`. But I'm unable to get div and its child. I tried this code

```
$('#attachmentDetail(' + index +') :input lstFiles['+index+'].IsDeleted').val("True");
```

but it says

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #attachmentDetail(0)

Is there any better way to get child of div?? I want to update `IsDeleted` value, and then hide this div.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way to get the child (and also the parent).  I would set a unique class on all the clickable `<a>` tags which trigger your code so that you can assign the event handlers by class.

```
$(".uniqueClass").click(function (e) {
  var $div = $(this).parent();
  var $deletedField = $div.find("input").first();
  $deletedField.val(true);
});
```

Now you can get rid of all those ID attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an id for your element, and use document.getElementById to get it, and then update it accordingly.

Comment: but i don't know which element is to be clicked so i need a proper way to get that element..